# How can I bundle an entire Vue app as a single UMD module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, module

I want to bundle a vue app with the styles and everything into a single UMD javascript module using vue-cli-service so that I can import it into *another* Vue app via my component distribution server. I am able to do this with one component on the serve, but I don't know how I'll be able to bundle an entire app and load it remotely into a separate app. I use this article as a guide https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/

This is where I am importing it:

```
  {
path: '/games',
component: GamesHome,
children: [
  {
    path: 'fun',
    component: () =>
      externalComponent(
        'http://localhost:8200/game/Game.cd590421a6d6835e7ae2.umd.min.js'
      ),
    name: 'Fun Game'
  }
] }
```

So basically how do I create a Vue app then bundle it entirely with CSS and all using vue-cli-service

Answer (score 7):

This is the problem which I have been trying to solve from day 1 ever since I started using VueJS. I will not consider a client side JS framework if it does not provide a solution for this problem.

I recently did a PoC in this and able to consume a VueJS application as module in another VueJS application. In my case I have a suite of VueJs applications where each of these applications is running in its own dedicated docker container. These applications have a lot of functionality which is common across all the applications. So I decided to move this common code (page layout, css frameworks etc) to a separate VueJS application and consume all existing VueJS applications as modules in this global application. I call this micro-app based architecture to differentiate it from micro-frontends based architecture because it does not use multiple client side JS frameworks and does not require another framework to achieve this. This is how the deployment architecture looks like in my case (you can ignore `kubernetes` specific stuff if your are not aware about it) -

[image: micro-app based architecture]

Coming back to implementation part, you need to take a step wise approach to convert a VueJS application to a micro-app.

- Lets say you project structure look as following (it shows only few files which require changes and NOT all the files) -

```
app-1
  public
    index.html
  src
    main.js
    App.vue
    router
      index.js
    store
      index.js
```

- Split your vuex state and routes files into global and application specific files -

```
app-1
  public
    index.html
  src
    main.js
    App.vue
    router
      app1
        index.js
      index.js
    store
      app1
        index.js
      index.js
```

- Make a copy of this project (global-app), remove `global-app` specific files from `app-1` and `app-1` from specific files from `global-app`. Also remove `index.html` and `App.vue` from  `app-1` project -

[image: Global app with micro app]

- Add `ROUTES` and `STORE_MODULES` variables to `index.html` file of `global-app` -

```
<head>
  ....
  ....
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const ROUTES = []
    const STORE_MODULES = {}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  ....
  ....
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app1/micro-app.umd.min.js"></script>
  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>
```

- Update `router\index.js` file of `global-app` for `ROUTES` variable -

```
const routes = [
  ....
  ....
]
routes.push(...ROUTES)

const router = new VueRouter({
```

- Update `store\index.js` file of `global-app` for `STORE_MODULES` variable -

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    ....
    ....
    modules: STORE_MODULES
})
```

- Clear content of `app-1\src\main.js` file and replace it with following content -

```
import routes from '@/router/app1'
import app1 from '@/store/app1'

ROUTES.push(...routes)

STORE_MODULES['app1'] = app1
```

- Define `build-app` command under `scripts` block of `package.json` file of `app-1` -

```
....
"scripts": {
  "build-app": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --formats umd-min --no-clean --name micro-app src/main.js"
},
....
```

- Now build and deploy these two applications in their dedicated containers and update nginx conf file of proxy container to forward requests to these containers as following -

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://global-app:80;     
}
    
location /app1/ {
    proxy_pass  http://app1:80/;     
}
```

- You can access global app by using IP address and port of nginx container.

I hope I have included all the steps which are required to implement micro-app based architecture. You can refer following git repositories which were created as part of this PoC -

```
https://github.com/mechcloud/large-app-docker
https://github.com/mechcloud/large-app
https://github.com/mechcloud/large-app-plugin1
```

While I am not an expert in the internals of client side JS frameworks, I believe this approach will work for other JS frameworks (Angular, React etc) as well.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I will try it out and get back to you +1